# Variable doesn't return from the function. (ReferenceError: Can't find variable: list2)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I'm new to React Native. I need to return the value of list2 to run the rest of the program. But it doesn't return. I know that its because I use useEffect which runs after the rest of the code. But I don't know how to return the variable(list2).

```
function contacts_list(data) {
  var list = []
  var list2 = ''
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    list.push(data[i]['name'])
    list2 = (list2 + "<Picker.Item label= \"" + data[i]['name'] + "\" " + " value= \"" + data[i]['name'] + "\" />")
  }
  //console.log(list2)
  return list2
}


export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts.Fields.Emails],
        });

        if (data.length > 0) {
          contact = data[0];
          //console.log(data)
          contacts_list(data)
        }
      }
    })();
  }, [])

  console.log(list2)
```

Comment: Do you have a `setState` call somewhere?

Comment: No. I don't have a setState

Comment: Why are you not putting the value of the return in a variable like that :  
var variables = contacts_list(data) ?

Comment: That worked... But I can't get the value out of the useEffect function

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much react-native is similar to react. I explain how this code will work in a react app, hopefully you will find the solution.
first of all the only thing that useEffect returns is cleanup function that will be called when component unmounts ( you can read more about it in react doc ), so if you need your data, you should store it in a variable outside of useEffect.
second, react only re-renders the component when 2 things change, one of your component props, or on of your states ( and in a default behavior, when component's parent rererenders ).
so what you need to do is something like this:

```
export default function App() {
const [ state, setState ] = useState ('');

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      ... rest of code

        if (data.length > 0) {
          contact = data[0];
          setState(contacts_list(data))
        }
      }
    })();
  }, [])

rest of your code ....
```